How to use AWS SSO with AWS-SDK 2.x
In my Nodejs app, I have been using aws-sdk (2.x) to get S3 objects. Below code works pretty fine.
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
S3 = new AWS.S3({
        accessKeyId: 'actual_accessKeyId',
        secretAccessKey: 'actual_secretAccessKey',
        region: 'region',
        signatureVersion: "v4",
});


const listBucketContent = (filePath, bucketName) => {
    const params = { Bucket: bucketName, Prefix: filePath };
    return S3.listObjects(params).promise();
};

However, as you can see above, I use hardcoded accesskey and secretaccesskey.

I actually don't want to use accesskey and secretAccesskey.
I have AWS SSO configured in my machine which looks something like below,
[profile AWS-XXX]
sso_start_url = https://XXX.XXX.com/start/#
sso_region = XXXXX
sso_account_id = XXXXXXXXXX
sso_role_name = XXXAdministratorAccess
region = XXXX

I want to use SSO directly but don't seem to find any way or articles to use it with aws-sdk.
So how can get S3 objects using AWS SSO?

If you're able to use the awscli with that credentials profile then you should equally be able to use the SDK. See SDK authentication with AWS if you're using v2 SDK.

Did any of the answers work?

Simply removing the static credentials (not providing any credentials at all) will make the SDK go through the list of all other possible credential locations - here is the relevant documentation for reference.
By default, it will use the default profile - if your SSO config is under the default profile, it should just work out of the box.
However, you can set the profile yourself by setting the AWS_PROFILE environment variable (setting process.env.AWS_PROFILE also works), or be even more explicit and directly load the SSO credentials provider.
Here is the example from the docs:
var creds = new AWS.SsoCredentials({profile: 'AWS-XXX'});
AWS.config.credentials = creds;


An example for the aws-sdk for C# is documented in AWS Docs here.
The equivalent of methods and class to use for AWS SDK for JavaScript v2. upcoming end of support for v2 so it's better to use the v3
but it seems that you need to do the login (manually or progrmatically) prior the execution of the code

Thanks for the pointers. However, need proper way to deal with Nodejs code.

Yes, maybe if you run your code in EC2 and not on a local macine you can attach to EC2 instance a profile that has permissions to access needed resources.

This question is for local machine, not for EC2. I want to be able to use AWS resources using local machine. If I set accessKey and secretAccesskey to local machine, it will work but as I said I don't want to set them locally instead I want to use AWS SSO login.

As I said in my response you need to handle the login programmatically or manually as in the docs, but If you login via aws sso (both ways) you still use / set your credentials locally, it's a temporary token  this is stored in .aws/sso.  some other ways is to "trust/assume service account" on prem machines like what's used in codedeploy and IAM Role Anywhere links here : https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/extend-aws-iam-roles-to-workloads-outside-of-aws-with-iam-roles-anywhere/   and  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/register-on-premises-instance-iam-session-arn.html

In SSO(The modern IAM), The key rotates every once in a while. You need to configure it only once with a role that you will assume during login and will correlate to the relevant account/environment/console you manage.
Follow this configuration, You can configure the role to have a limited permissions.
More documentation here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-sso.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/getting-your-credentials.html
